# In Arkham Horror 3rd edition can you use the evade action vs "shrouded" creatures?

Tags: arkham-horror-3rd-edition, arkham-horror-secrets-of-the-order

Can you use the evade action vs "shrouded" creatures? If so how since you can't look the side of the card with its statistics.

Answer (score 2):

From the [rules reference](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/70/15/70156879-aefe-441e-94a0-1a816872058d/ahb01_rules-reference-compressed.pdf)

> You can perform the evade action only if you are engaged with one or more monsters.

And from [Secrets of the Order Expansion Rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/d8/2e/d82ede15-9f70-41e9-a002-65a13c15d8cd/ahb06_rulesbook_compressed.pdf) the example given says

> During the monster phase, the Raging Poltergeist moves into Agatha’s space and engages her (2). The monster card flips to the engaged side and becomes a Confounding Specter, revealing that its health is two.

You can't use evade without being engaged to a creature, but once they are engaged you reveal the side of the card with the statistics. Once an investigator is engaged to a creature, they can use the evade action.